# как правильно переписывать auth_key токен юзера,при входе его с другого устройства , (создаю api`шку)

Tags: php, python, api, oauth2, fastapi

Как реализовать вход на сайт с нескольких устройств(браузеров), при том что auth_key переписывается при каждом входе? Как я понял при каждом логине auth_key токен должен перезаписываться на новый сгенерированный случайно , и отдается пользователю для последующих запросов в апи(и вписывается в колонку auth_key), но если юзер залогиниться в двух местах - токен первого логина(на фронте сохраненный) будет недействительным, как с этим бороться? спасибо большое!

```
    @app.post("/token")
async def login(form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends()):
    user_dict = fake_users_db.get(form_data.username)
    if not user_dict:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Incorrect username or password")
    user = UserInDB(**user_dict)
    hashed_password = to_hash(form_data.password)
    if not hashed_password == user.hashed_password:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Incorrect username or password")

    return {"access_token": user.username, "token_type": "bearer"}
```

Comment: Не нужно его переписывать, нужно создать список ключей (токенов) для пользователя для того, чтобы он мог войти любое количество раз, и отслеживать их валидность.

Comment: глупый вопрос - просто таблицу создать? спасибо большое

Comment: На ваше усмотрение, хоть таблицу, хоть в Redis или другой системе кэширования типа memcache с назначением ключу периода валидности.

Answer (score 0):

Создам новую таблицу для токенов и буду валидировать их по времени

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]